# Unity3D C#. How do I move a plane up, down, side to side at a fixed point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am trying to make a board game and i'm struggling to find a way to move a fixed plane up, down, side to side.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Game Idea:
Ball Moving 3D Maze Puzzle

Comment: `Is there a way to achieve this?` .. yes, there are probably multiple. Please try implement something and coke back with a specific question.

Comment: So you're asking how to rotate a plane? This is not a novel question. What have you looked up and attempted to implement?